# How to fix multiple Nuget objects causing the error "assembly...must be strong signed in order to be marked as prerequisite"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 C# Win Forms app in Visual Studio 2017.  When I ran the app, I got an error saying "assembly...must be strong signed in order to be marked as prerequisite" for several NuGetpackages.  I began looking for reasons online and finally found a suggestion to look in the object explorer. In the object explorer, I can see that there aree multiples of the same object:

[image]

The older version is pointing to " C:\Users\MyName\.nuget\packages\package.dll" and the newer version is pointing to "C:\repos\My Project\packages\package.dll".

I can't find any reference in the solution to the C:\User\MyName\.nuget folder.  I've gone through the NuGetPackage Manager and updated and also uninstalled/reinstalled the packages, but I can't get rid of the old reference.  If I look in the References under the project, I only see the newer version.  I also tried deleting all the bin and obj folders from the solution.  I even looked as the csproj file, but can't find any reference to the older version.  The only place the old version shows up is in that object browser.  How do I get rid of these references to the older version of these NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0):

What did you change since it last worked? .NET 4.7.2 is very old, and I would expect that it has problems with any nuget packages newer than around 10 years. The nuget handling has changed significantly since 4.7.2 was released.

I would do a step forward and update your application to .NET 6.0. Allows you to use most of the newest nugets and also solves the strong naming problem for good, since .NET 6.0+ no longer uses strong naming the way .NET Framework did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, this is the version being used where I work so I can't change that.  Also, nothing (as far as I know) has changed in the code.

Comment: Oh dear, that sounds bad. You should really tell your boss to invest in upgrading. Problems (including security related problems) are likely to arise from using such old stuff.